# Issue with login using selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I am getting following error

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@placeholder='User ID']"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.70). Let me know how can i pass user id here
```

Comment: Several things can be going wrong here. You could have multiple `input` elements located by the XPath -- if you are just using `find_element`, this may cause an issue. Another issue is the element being nested in an `iframe` element higher up in the DOM. Without the URL or full HTML for the page you are testing, this problem will be difficult to solve.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without additional context, I can only recommend that you wait on the element before sending keys to it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


input = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='User ID']")))

input.send_keys("userId")
```

Full working sample as requested by asker:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://kite.zerodha.com/connect/login?api_key=b8w63qg9m4c3zubd&sess_id=bW3U1OwidO97o11scfeTbyfX4j5tViNp")

input = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='User ID']")))

input.send_keys("userId")

sleep(10) # this sleep is here so you can visually verify the text was sent.

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

The above code has succeeded every time I have run it.

Comment: Thanks Christine, Below is the URL link browser.get('https://kite.zerodha.com/connect/login?api_key=b8w63qg9m4c3zubd&v=3')

input = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='User ID']")))
input.send_keys("XXXXX"), ur code worked 1 out 5 tries, rest of times i got time out error

Comment: @AravindRajReddy as you can see Christine's answer worked but you should just add a longer wait... `WebDriverWait(browser, 30)` that should do the trick! good answer.

Comment: It fails after 30 seconds 
browser.get('https://kite.zerodha.com/connect/login?api_key=b8w63qg9m4c3zubd&v=3')
input = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='User ID']")))
input.send_keys("XXX")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='User ID']")))
  File "C:\Users\aarthisastha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
TimeoutException

Comment: Interesting that the code is only working sometimes, but not other times. If it works once, it's the correct solution, but may need to be configured differently -- you could try experimenting by changing `presence_of_element_located` to `visibility_of_element_located` and, as @MosheSlavin has mentioned, increasing the wait time. After looking at your page HTML, there are no other special cases interfering with the element, so the `wait.until` should be all you need. I've updated my solution with a different wait for you to try.

Comment: @AravindRajReddy I have tested my code in my own environment and it has successfully located User ID 5 times in a row. I believe changing `presence_of_element_located` to `visibility_of_element_located` helped.